# Can't scanf int in assembly

Tags: assembly, architecture, scanf, 32bit-64bit, att

I already tried to scanf string and it worked fine. Now I'm trying to scanf int and it doesn't work.

```
   .data 
    intFormat: .string "%i"
    .bss
    intBuffer:  .space 10
    .text 
    .globl main 
    main: 

    #Get answers
    push $intBuffer    #2nd argument for scanf
    push $intFormat #1st argument of scanf
    call scanf          #scanf ("%s",intBuffer);

    #Show answers
    push $intBuffer
    push $intFormat
    call printf


    #Exiting
    pushl $0 
    call exit
```

But when i'm trying to scanf string it work fine
Here is string code

```
.data 
intFormat: .string "%s"
.bss
stringBuffer:  .space 10
.text 
.globl main 
main: 

#Get answers
push $intBuffer    #2nd argument for scanf
push $intFormat #1st argument of scanf
call scanf          #scanf ("%s",stringBuffer);

#Show answers
push $intBuffer
push $intFormat
call printf


#Exiting
pushl $0 
call exit
```

I also tried to make int as %d. It doesn't work to. 
scanf ("%s",stringBuffer); This is scanf fuction. So in assembly i push arguments form right to left. first is stringbuffer/intbuffer and then %s/%i. It works for string fine but for int output is like : 134520872

I tried to push $400 as argument and it printf me 400.

Using  gcc -m32 lab3scanf.s -g -o exe1 to compile

Comment: Note that if you were going to `ret` instead of calling `exit`, you'd need to pop args off the stack (with `add esp, 4*4`, because you didn't `mov` into the space you allocated for scanf's args, but instead allocated new space for printfs args with 2 more `push`.

Comment: Also, if you'd used a debugger to look at stack memory before the call, it would have been clear that you were pushing a large integer.  (And you might have recognized it as an address if you saw it in hex)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanning works fine (you can check that it does using a debugger). What is wrong is your call to `printf`.  Remember, in C you write

```
scanf("%i", &buffer);
```

to scan an integer and

```
printf("%i", buffer);
```

to print it.  Your code effectively does

```
printf("%i", &buffer);
```

which is undefined behaviour, wrong, and in your case prints the address of `buffer`.  To fix this code, you need to pass the content of `intBuffer`, not its address, to `printf`.

Comment: @Fenrir It's my pleasure.

Comment: You can't really say the OP's hand-written asm has C undefined behaviour.  In 32-bit x86, pointers and integers are the same size, and casting between the two is a no-op, so the code is also equivalent to `printf("%i", (int)&buffer);` which is well defined.  i.e. it prints the pointer as an integer.  There's no access to more bytes than passed, or any Bad Stuff.